# 96 Toyota Camry won't stay started

Tags: engine, electrical, toyota, troubleshooting

My 96 Camry starts first time every time then stalls after 10-20 seconds?  Last year it ran fine but rarely would stall @ running speed.  I had to set for 2-3min before it would start then it ran fine.  If I tried to start it immediately it started then stalled within 2-5 seconds.  Ran for months without issue now won't stay started @ all.  Local mechanic replaced throttle position sensor (with used one) and the igniter?  Checked fuel pump, OK!

Comment: This could be an underreading MAF, bad O2 sensor, malfunctioning IACV, etc. Need more info (diagnostic codes, fuel trims, etc.) to provide better guidance

Comment: @ziad  this in a non-MAF engine. On a cold start its not looking at the O2 yet. Yes on the IACV, maybe ECT.  I agree more info is needed. Hot or cold? V6 or 4 cyl?

Answer (score -1):

I take it that your mechanic hass scanned the vehicle and found no faults. These sort of problems can point to the transpnder in your car key, or the transponder in the steering coluum or its wiring. At the very worst case your engines ECU immobiliser may be on the way out.

Comment: The 96 Camry did not have a key transponder or engine immobilizer (at least not the North American/Canada version). If it had them, I wouldn't think they would let the engine start for only a few seconds, and then work again indefinitely after a few minutes wait, though almost anything's possible with intermittent mystery problems

Comment: Having a factory immobilizer in a 99 camry, I can tell you that is not the case. The Immobilizer will not kill the car if the transponder is removed. Once it's on, it's on until turned off at the ignition key switch. (I had a plain blank key turn on the car while holding the chipped key near it, then removed the chipped key right after ignition.)

Answer (score -1):

If a vehicle starts but then the engine stops very soon after that, chances are that the alternator is dead as the battery without the alternator has only so much charge to sustain the motion for a brief while.